# Django multiple images for post to render

Tags: html, django, django-models, rendering

For the past few days I have been trying to give access to the admin user to upload multiple images/slides for every single post, one idea I had in mind was nesting a for loop inside the posts for loop that for every post, render also every image associated with it but it seem's I cant get it quite right.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'post_pics')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title} - {self.category}"


def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.post.title 
    slug = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)



class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default= None, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name= 'Images')
    image  = models.ImageField( upload_to = get_image_filename, verbose_name = 'Images')

def __str__(self):
    return f"imazh per {self.post}"
```

and my Html:

```html
<div class="post-list-container">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="post-container">
        
    <div class="post-top">

         

> Focus on the for loop here

        {% for post.Images in post.Images %}
            <img src="{{ post.Images.url }}">
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="post-title"><a href="#"><h1>{{ post.title }} </h1></a></div>
            <div class="post-images">
                <img class="rounded" src="{{ post.image.url }}">
            </div>
                    
        </div>
                    
                
        <div class="post-middle">
                
                    <div class="post-content"><p>   {{ post.content }}</p> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-bottom">
                
                    <div class="post-category"><a href="{% url 'by-category' post.category %}"><h2>{{ post.category }}</h2></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-date_posted"><h1>{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </article>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Is there any way to render those images this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Post` will have a related set, which is what you refer to that reverse relationship as.

By default, django will make the relationship on a `Post` instance `images_set` because it takes your model name on the relationship & adds `_set`.

You can also choose your own related name by setting the `related_name` attribute on the FK field. ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name))

Here's an example;

```py
class Map(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        related_name='maps',
        verbose_name=_('members')
    )

# Reverse relationship:
User.maps.all()
```

Or in python using your models;

```py
post = Post.objects.first()

print(f"Images in post {post.title}")

for image in post.images_set.all():
    print(image.url)
```

So without a custom `related_name`, your template loop would be something like;

```
        {% for image in post.images_set.all %}
            <img src="{{ image.url }}">
        {% empty %}
            <p>No images found</p>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for help, much appreciated.